# Загружать картику с интернета в итем RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, парсер, recyclerview, url

Есть список RecyclerView, который имеет два итема: TextView и ImageView. ImageView имеет картинку по умолчанию, TextView содержит url на разные картикни в интернете, Textview заполняется данными с бд с помощью AsyncTask. Нужно, чтобы после того, как создастья список RecyclerView вместо картинки по умолчанию загрузилась картинка по определенной ссылке. Подскажите, как я могу это сделать.
Пытался через Picasso, но не выходит.

Comment: может сам код покажите? примеров в интернете полно

Comment: Разрешение на интернет не забыли в манифесте указать?