# Загрузка картинки по url c помощью Picasso в RecyclerView после его создания

Tags: android, парсер, recyclerview, picasso, recyclerview.adapter

Есть список `RecyclerView`, который имеет два итема: `TextView` и `ImageView`. `ImageView` имеет картинку по умолчанию, `TextView` содержит url на разные картикни в интернете, `Textview` заполняется данными с бд с помощью `AsyncTask`. Нужно, чтобы после того, как создастья список `RecyclerView` вместо картинки по умолчанию загрузилась картинка по определенной ссылке. После создания адаптера пытаюсь заполнить `ImageView` данными с помощью Picasso, но получаю ошибку : `Illegalstateexception target host is null`.

Есть вариант загружать картинку в `ViewHolder`, в методе `onBindViewHolder`, но тогда при плохом подключении к интернету происходит слишком долгая загрузка приложения, что не подходит. Нужно, чтобы заполнилось стандартной картинкой, а потом уже подгружало.

ListItem.java

```
public class ListItem {

private String head;
private String desc;

private Drawable webSiteImage;

private List<String> headList;
private List<String> urlList;
private List<String> imgUrlList;

private String imgUrl;

public ListItem() {
}


public String getHead() {
    return head;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setHead(String head) {
    this.head = head;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public List<String> getHeadList() {
    return headList;
}

public List<String> getUrlList() {
    return urlList;
}

public void setHeadList(List<String> headList) {
    this.headList = headList;
}

public void setUrlList(List<String> urlList) {
    this.urlList = urlList;
}

public String getImgUrl() {
    return imgUrl;
}

public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}

public List<String> getImgUrlList() {
    return imgUrlList;
}

public void setImgUrlList(List<String> imgUrlList) {
    this.imgUrlList = imgUrlList;
}

public Drawable getWebSiteImage() {
    return webSiteImage;
}

public void setWebSiteImage(Drawable webSiteImage) {
    this.webSiteImage = webSiteImage;
}
}
```

Адаптер MyRecViewAdapter.java

```
public class MyRecViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private List<ListItem> listItems;
private Context context;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvHead;
    public TextView tvDesc;
    public ImageView ivWebImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_head);
        tvDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
        ivWebImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivWebImage);
    }



}

public MyRecViewAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    //return our view
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

    holder.tvHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
    holder.tvDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());

    holder.ivWebImage.setImageDrawable(listItem.getWebSiteImage());
    /*Picasso.with(context).load(listItems.get(position).getImgUrl())
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .into(holder.ivWebImage);*/

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public static final String TAG  = "mLog";

@BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@BindView(R.id.button)
Button button;

private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ListItem item;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    OperationsDB operationsDB = new OperationsDB(this);
    operationsDB.execute();

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    try {
        item = operationsDB.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    List<ListItem> itemRecView = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < item.getHeadList().size(); i++) {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.setHead(item.getHeadList().get(i));
        listItem.setDesc(item.getUrlList().get(i));
        listItem.setImgUrl(item.getImgUrlList().get(i));
        listItem.setWebSiteImage(d);
        itemRecView.add(listItem);
    }

    adapter = new MyRecViewAdapter(itemRecView, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

           MyRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new 
    MyRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder(
            recyclerView);

   Picasso.with(this).load(listItem.getImgUrlList.get(1))
   .into(viewHolder.ivWebImage);



}


}


private static class OperationsDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ListItem> {

    Document document;

    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> activityWeakReference;
    OperationsDB(MainActivity context) {
        activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }



    @Override
    protected ListItem doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        /* Создание объекта класа для заполнения коллекций данными, которыми
            будут заполнены итемы RecyclerView */
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();

        // Коллекция веб ссылок, полученных из БД
        List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
        urls.addAll(getData().getUrlList());

        // Заполнение коллекции ссылок и заголовков сайтов
        listItem.setUrlList(urls);
        listItem.setHeadList(getData().getHeadList());


        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {

            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(urls.get(i)).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Element img = document.select("img").first();
            String imgSrc = img.absUrl("src");



            list.add(imgSrc);
        }


        listItem.setImgUrlList(list);
        return listItem;
    }

    private ListItem getData() {
        DBAdapter db;
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(activityWeakReference.get(),
                DBAdapter.class, DB_NAME).build();

        WebSitesDao webSitesDao = db.webSitesDao();

        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.setHeadList(webSitesDao.getColumn());
        listItem.setUrlList(webSitesDao.getUrl());

        return  listItem;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Я, конечно не уверен, но скорей всего ошибка тут не в пикассо, а в жести, которая происходит в цикле, где заполняется itemRecView  лист.

Comment: Нет, ошибка возникает, когда использую пикассо. Без этой строчки кода всё работает.

Comment: А что у вас идет непосредственно после setAdapter? вы какой-то viewholder создаете с какой-то целью... И стектрейс вы не приложили, не прочитали, на тех строках все и падает поди.

Comment: Создаю viewholder, чтобы обратится к итему recyclerview и изменить его содержимое картинкой, полученной с помощью picasso

Comment: @Сергей тоже склоняюсь к тому что у вас тормоза из-за списка. Сначала вы делаете AsyncTask, тут же берете кусок данных, полученный из другого потока... сдается мне - на фоне общих тормозов, получение данных в адаптере -
listItems.get(position).getImgUrl() приводит к нормальным таким проблемам с производительностью при запуске.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Загружать картику с интернета в итем RecyclerView Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/791781/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-recyclerview-android)

Comment: @AndreyMihalev можете подсказать, каким образом это лучше можно реализовать?

Comment: @Сергей зачем вы используете 2 цикла? Сначала при составлении массива, потом в другой массив а уже его передаете в адаптер. Отправляйте данные напрямую в адаптер, без использования 2 цикла. И пусть адаптер обрабатывает данные как нужно.